# Status 404 After YouTube GetUploadToken Request Using GWT RequestBuilder

Tags: java, gwt, youtube-api

I am trying to dispatch a POST request to get an upload token from YouTube using RequestBuilder from the client-side of my GWT app.

I am trying to build the request as described by the following YouTube API documentation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading#Browser_based_uploading

The following is my client-side GWT code:

```
// BODY
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
        + "<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\""
        + "xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\""
        + "xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\">"
        + "<media:group>"
        + "<media:title type=\"plain\">MyTitle</media:title>"
        + "<media:description type=\"plain\">"
        + "My description."
        + "</media:description>"
        + "<media:category scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat\">"
        + "People"
        + "</media:category>"
        + "<media:keywords>word1, word2</media:keywords>"
        + "</media:group>"
        + "</entry>");

String requestBody = sb.toString();

// HEADER
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "https://" + YOUTUBE_HOST + "/action/GetUploadToken");
rb.setHeader("Host", YOUTUBE_HOST);
rb.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=" + CHAR_ENCODING);
rb.setHeader("X-GData-Key", MY_CLIENT_KEY);
rb.setHeader("GData-Version", "2");
try {
    rb.setHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(requestBody.getBytes(CHAR_ENCODING).length));
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Window.alert(e.getMessage());
}
rb.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AUTHORIZATION_CODE);

// CALL
try {
    rb.sendRequest(requestBody, new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            Document dom = XMLParser.parse(response.getText());

            Node urlNode = dom.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0);
            String url = urlNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

            Node tokenNode = dom.getElementsByTagName("token").item(0);
            String token = tokenNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable t) {
            callback.onFailure(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
catch (RequestException e) {
    callback.onFailure(e.getMessage());
}
```

The following is my request as displayed in Chrome's developer tools:

```
Request URL:https://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

**Request Headers**

```
:host:gdata.youtube.com
:method:OPTIONS
:path:/action/GetUploadToken
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
access-control-request-headers:origin, x-gdata-key, authorization, content-type, gdata-version
access-control-request-method:POST
origin:http://127.0.0.1:8888
referer:http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
```

**Response Headers**

```
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:117
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Thu, 06 Dec 2012 14:29:20 GMT
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:GSE
status:404 Not Found
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-gdata-user-country:US
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

As seen above, I am getting a "404 Not Found" error after dispatching the request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not super familiar with GWT, but I noticed something peculiar. The request that Chrome is reporting is, in fact, an `OPTIONS` request, not a `POST` as the YouTube API requires. I am able to reproduce the 404 when sending an arbitrary `OPTIONS` request to this URL.

Your code indicates that you are attempting to send a `POST` request. However, I assume this is a cross-origin request, which would be governed by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite) example of cross-site requests using GWT. It is possible that the odd behavior of sending an `OPTIONS` request instead of a `POST` request is due to the code treating this as if it were a same-site request.

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube API's CORS support has been broken for about two weeks now. I'm assured by the engineering team that it will be fixed very, very soon (hopefully today). That's what's causing the error you're seeing.

You can follow https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/issues/detail?id=9 for updates. (It's mainly been affecting YouTube Direct Lite, as there aren't many other apps out there that rely on CORS.)